# Should a MV3 extension use chrome.runtime.sendMessage() or serviceWorker.controller.postMessage() for messaging?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, web-extension

The [Chrome docs mention `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` and `chrome.runtime.onMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/):

```
const response = await chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"});
```

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage(messageHandler)
```

To communicate between a service worker and a content script.

However I already have messaging working within my Manifest V3 extension, between my service worker and a popup, using a different API.

In my service worker:

```
self.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  handleMessage(event.data);
});
```

and in my popup:

```
const SERVICE_WORKER = globalThis?.navigator?.serviceWorker || null;
SERVICE_WORKER.controller.postMessage({
  topic: "getSecretKey",
});
```

**Which of `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()` and `serviceWorker.controller.postMessage()` is preferable for messaging between extension components (service workers, popups, and content scripts)?**

Do they have similar use cases or different limits?

Some investigation seems to be `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()` is designed for messaging specifically for extensions, whereas `serviceWorker.controller.postMessage()` is for general purpose webapps with service workers. But I suspect there may be more to it.

Comment: Would `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()` or `chrome.runtime.connect()` allow passing transferable objects? If not, can i use `serviceWorker.controller.postMessage()` to send and receive transferable objects among content.js and service-worker.js? Just asking.

Comment: @Redu heya! My Extension knowledge is a little rusty - best to actually ask a new  question (and link to this one to show you did some research before asking).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Data types

- Service Worker messaging uses the [structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm) which allows more data types e.g. ArrayBuffer, Blob/File, DataView, Date, Error, ImageBitmap, ImageData, Map, RegExp, Set, TypedArray, and the [transferable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Transferable_objects) data parameter in `postMessage()`.
- `chrome` messaging only allows JSON-compatible types in Chrome (null, boolean, number, string, Object/Array that recursively consists of these types); Firefox also supports the clonable types listed above.

#### Targeting

- Service Worker messaging opens one directional connection.
- Service Worker messaging doesn't have a concept of [simple messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple) (sending a request and receiving a response), so to properly handle asynchronously overlapped messages you'll need to implement your own queuing/ordering system.
- Service Worker messaging doesn't work with a content script; only a `chrome-extension://` context (page or frame or worker) can use it.
- `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` sends to all frames of the tab unless you specify `frameId` in the [options parameter](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-sendMessage).
- `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` broadcasts to **all** chrome-extension:// contexts i.e. the background script, the popup(s), the options page, all extension tabs, all iframes that point to an html file from web_accessible_resources.

P.S. No need for `?.` because SW is always usable in a context from its own origin, i.e. you can just use `navigator.serviceWorker.controller`.